# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'JayDeBeApi3'

Tags: python-3.x, rhel

**I don't understand why Python3 is giving me an module not find error on importing JayDeBeApi3 module.**

## import JayDeBeApi3

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'JayDeBeApi3'**

**Please below, JayDeBeApi3 is successfully installed**

## pip3 install JayDeBeApi3

Collecting JayDeBeApi3
  Using cached JayDeBeApi3-1.3.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: py4j in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from JayDeBeApi3)
Installing collected packages: JayDeBeApi3
  Running setup.py install for JayDeBeApi3 ... done
**Successfully installed JayDeBeApi3-1.3.2**

**BELOW IS PYTHONPATH SETTING**

Python 3.6.0 (default, Nov 27 2017, 11:04:30)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import sys
> > >       print (sys.path)
> > >       ['', '/usr/local/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

**# locate JayDeBeApi3**

usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/JayDeBeApi3-1.3.2-py3.6.egg-info
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/JayDeBeApi3-1.3.2-py3.6.egg-info/PKG-INFO
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/JayDeBeApi3-1.3.2-py3.6.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/JayDeBeApi3-1.3.2-py3.6.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/JayDeBeApi3-1.3.2-py3.6.egg-info/installed-files.txt
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/JayDeBeApi3-1.3.2-py3.6.egg-info/requires.txt
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/JayDeBeApi3-1.3.2-py3.6.egg-info/top_level.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading JayDeBeApi3 1.3 from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JayDeBeApi3/1.3 and installing it locally resolved the issue for me. Though, I am sure, that's not an actual solution.